# Remove lines efficiently in Vim

Tags: vim, text-editing

**How can you remove given lines efficiently in Vim?**

I want to remove all lines which match this

```
:g!/div/
```

I unsuccessfully ran:

```
:g!/div/s/^*//g
```

Comment: All I know is that I use the 'dd' command to remove a line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove all lines that match div

```
:g/div/d
```

To remove all lines that don't match div

```
:g!/div/d
```

Answer (score 6):

```
:g!/div/d
```

Works just fine to do what you want.

Comment: Vim certainly isn't only used on servers. Potentially anyone who does any programming could benefit from this question. I certainly did, and I'm not affiliated at all with servers in my work.

Comment: @thr4wn: superuser isn't the site for servers, that's serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

```
:V/div/d
```

In case of larger files, it might be faster to:

```
:%!grep div
```